# Image gallery inside fieldset?

Tags: sencha-touch-2, photo-gallery

I designing edit form using fieldset. For example,

```
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'nameEn',
        label: 'Name (English)',
        placeholder: '',
        autoCapitalize: false,
        required: true,
        clearIcon: true
    },
    {
        xtype: 'textareafield',
        name: 'descriptionEn',
        label: 'Description (English)'
    },
    {
        xtype: 'togglefield',
        name: 'verified',
        label: 'Verified'
    }
]
```

And now I need photos (for view, but upload/remove is possible in future). I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for display you can use the `xtype:image` ([documentation here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Img)), and for upload you can use the `xtype:textfield` with an `inputType:'file'` property. However, you should note that on iOS you may not be able to do file upload without packaging an app (as mentioned in [this forum post](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?127683-Sencha-Touch-File-Upload)). If you want users to be able to take a picture with the camera you can use a button, and in the handler use the [`Ext.device.Camera` component](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.device.Camera).

If you want multiple photos you may want to use an [`hbox` layout](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.layout.HBox) around your `image` components.

Good luck!

EDIT: Here's an example of a `panel` with an `hbox` layout and horizontal scrolling. Basically, the simplest image gallery you can make in Sencha Touch (I think):

```
{
  xtype: 'panel',
  layout: 'hbox',
  scrollable: { direction: 'horizontal' },
  items: [
    {
      xtype: 'image',
      src: 'path/to/image.png'
    },
    {
      xtype: 'image',
      src: 'path/to/another/image.jpg'
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I need more then one photo. And I don't know how to build interface (not functionality).

Comment: Well, you can add multiple items in the `hbox`... I'll update the answer, maybe it'll get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Ok, but maybe image carousel will be better? I try to find examples of this interface - no result

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a carousel, what functionality are you looking for?

Comment: Web gallery inside record modification form